# Storing collection of HTML elements in variable for later use

Tags: jquery

Here is a jQuery issue that I come across and always have to resolve using methods I'm not proud of.

I'm attempting to store a collection of elements for later assessment. The problem is that every time I try to access and apply any function to it, the error console reports the it is not a function. I'm convinced that I have a misunderstand of how jQuery works. Nonetheless, I'd like to be pointed in the right direction. Here is the code I am using:

```
var products = $('ul.products');
var productLists = []
$.each(products, function (i) {
    productLists[i] = products[i].children('li');
    console.log(productLists[i]);
});
```

and here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'children' of object #<HTMLUListElement> is not a function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to call a jQuery method off an HTMLElement. Try wrapping the element reference in a new jQuery object:

```
productLists[i] = $(products[i]).children('li');
```

Within `$.each`, you can use the keyword `this` to reference the current item being handled. So instead of calling `products[i]`, you could just as easily say `this`:

```
$.each( products, function() {
  productsList.push( $(this).children("li") );
});
```

Note also that jQuery already stores a collection of references to elements when you make a selection:

```
var productList = $("ul.products li"); // All list items in ul.products
```

You can then manipulate all of these as you wish later. If you need your own copies of them, to ensure they will exist later when you want to tamper with them, you can use `.clone`:

```
var productList = $("ul.products li").clone();
```

Comment: Incredible. This worked automatically. You have saved me many future headaches. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1416503 My pleasure. Please consider up-voting this solution if you found it helpful, and also consider the latest addition to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: the OP can't upvote yet with only 6 rep.  I gave you one, though.

Comment: Another upvote. The OP could also accept this as the answer, right? (HINT) :)

Comment: After JonSkeet, BalusC, BillTheLizard ... Jonathan Sampson. Only if I could have `follow` functionality in SO.  +1 anyways

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use the each method on jquery collection object. So another way of doing the same thing could be:

```
$('ul.products').each(function(){
  productsList.push( $(this).children("li") );
})
```

Matter of choice though, I always preferred this approach when dealing with jQuery collection.